# Show/Select and Order By SUM MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this data

```
ID | Name | views
1  | one  | 10
2  | one  | 10
3  | three| 30
4  | four | 5
5  | four | 5
```

**How i can show orderby sum of views ?**

output like this

```
three  | 30
one    | 20
four   | 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, SUM(VIEWS) FROM **--TABLE NAME--** ORDER BY SUM(VIEWS) DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(VIEWS) FROM **--TABLE NAME--**
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY SUM(VIEWS) DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT has no place here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next simple query:

```
SELECT
  `Name`, SUM(Views) `TotalViews` 
FROM `Data` 
GROUP BY `Name` 
ORDER BY `TotalViews` DESC;
```

Here the example [SQLize online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/76147d83a2b82f8767507858ff1a1b56/)